# How do you calculate F-value for three groups, given only the mean and standard deviation in Python

Tags: python, statsmodels, anova

I am learning about power analysis for different scenarios in Python, e.g. for three groups (assuming equal sample in each group).
I've seen videos demo for SPSS and other softwares, where you simply put in mean and stdev for each group and the total # of groups and then it gives you an output of effect size. So I assume that's achievable in Python too.

I've done something similar for two groups through t-test, being 1) determine effect size through Cohen's d formula 2) plug into TTestIndPower function in Python to get sample size.

However, let's say I have **three** groups, and I expected group 1: mean - 50, stdev - 2; group 2: mean - 61, stdev - 4; group 3: mean - 49, stdev - 3.0. I want to calculate how many sample is needed for each group. I know I can use FTestAnovaPower once I get the effect size, but I just don't know how to get that from just the mean and stdev.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a SO question as it's about understanding the *statistics*. This question may be better asked at [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=f+test+sample+size). Once you know the equation, if you still cannot get your code to work as expected, then come back and ask for help in understanding what is wrong with the code.

Comment: looks like https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.oneway.effectsize_oneway.html  (but I don't remember the details right now)

Comment: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/stats/tests/test_oneway.py#L51 unit tests with examples

Comment: and `anova_generic` computes one-way anova from summary statistics https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.oneway.anova_generic.html